# TextViews overlapping in Relative layout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout, overlap

I have these two TextViews in my content_main, I am a beginner and i can't figure out why are they overlapping in the center, I tried chanign everything and it still doesn't work.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textColor="#1a237e" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/temperatureTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#00bcd4" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to stack them, use LinearLayout. If you're trying to stack them and you HAVE to use RelativeLayout and stack them, remove `layout_alignParentTop` on the second TextView and add `layout_below=@id/nameTextView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this code on the second TextView(@`tempratureTextView`):

`layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"        
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#1a237e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"        
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/temperatureTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="#00bcd4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout xml above will work. 
Besides that, I noticed that you are trying to use `android:gravity` to position your TextView on top and bottom. This will not work because `android:gravity` only set the gravity of the content(the text) in your TextView. Use `android:layout_gravity` to set the TextView's gravity within the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

*layout_alignParentTop* makes sure that your view stays at top,regardless of other views.
Same thing about *layout_alignParentBottom* it makes view stick to bottom.
In your scenario you want these TextView one below other, So you have to specify android using, *layout_below* for the bottom element.
Anyway you have the answers as others has provided it,just making it clear about reason.